# Return additional values from MonteCarloSimulation

Tags: drake

Is there a way to return addition values besides the scalar result from the `MonteCarloSimulation`? I've looked through the [documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__analysis.html) and [this example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/examples/multibody/pendulum_lqr_monte_carlo_analysis.py) but don't see a way to do it.

My use case:
In `make_simulator` I generate a GaussianVector using the generator, then do some processing on that vector and I want to return that value together with my result. It's like the "domain" to the "image" and I need both to do further calculations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to return more data from the output function. The `MonteCarloSimulation` returns a list of results, where each result has only `generator_snapshot` (a RNG) and `output` (a float).

The function `make_simulator` is supposed to *only* depend on the `generator` is was given.  So in theory, you could take the `generator_snapshot` and call a function similar to your `make_simulator` again, to recompute the Gaussian vector, image, or whatever else you like from the RNG. This might waste some computation time, but should always be possible.

There is also another way: the order of list of results returned by `MonteCarloSimulation` *exactly matches* the order of calls that happen to `make_simulator`

So if you are careful with your bookkeeping, inside of `make_simulator` you could append your extra data into a global list of "images".  Then after Monte Carlo finishes, you would have e.g. 100 images an 100 simulation outputs, and you could `zip()` them together.

In summary: there is no way to *return* more data from `make_simulator`, but you can change your `make_simulator` to copy any data it needs into somewhere you can grab it later.